# Jenkins: How to check server directory exist in Nexus with powershell?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

We using Jenkins. 
I want to upload a directory+files, from a directory on windows server into Nexus with powershell.

But before doing this I want to check if this directory already exist in Nexus.

With wget I can download the directory+files from Nexus into my workspace of Jenkins.

But I want just check the directory/file by url ("http://xxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz/") if it exist in Nexus on the server.

I have tried: 
- Test-Path -Path, 
- Get-SpWeb (is not recognized), 
- invoke-request, 
- HTTPRequest =[System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('url').

I have tried a lot but invoke request and the HTTPRequest is working if the directory exist. But if it not exist I get the 404 error ($HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()) or it hangs...

I looking for an example/tutorial of powershell (Jenkins) which is checking if a directory/file "http://xxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz/" in Nexus on a server exist or NOT exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Only" this was working for me with Jenkins and I don't know now why -Mehthod HEAD is necessary and what it does, but at least it works within Jenkins:

```
try {
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri $url
    $status = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__

} catch {
    $status = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__
} # END try {...} catch {...} 

if (($status -eq 200) -Or ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($status))) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$status = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://xxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz/).StatusCode
if ($status -eq 200) {
   #do stuff when url exists
}
```

Comment: This one I have tried. If the url exist no problem, in less than an second the code is executed. 
BUT if the uri does not exist than it "hangs". I don't know what is going than but after 3 or 5 min. I aborted the Jenkins job

Comment: Probably you will have the same behaviour in your browser. If you write a non existing path in your browser, how it responds? The problem may be in the server, not in the script